# How to raycast with a given angle?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, raycasting

[image]

The green point is the Vector p1 while red point is the Vector p2. I could access the ray angle by using `p2.sub(p1).angle()` method.

Given:

`float oberserverAngle = p2.cpy().sub(p1).angle();`

```
RayCastCallback callback = new RayCastCallback() {

    @Override 
    public float reportRayFixture(Fixture fixture, Vector2 point, Vector2 normal, float fraction) {
    }        

}
```

`world.rayCast(callback, p1, p2);`

Now when I do this, the fov is not right, what am I missing?

```
shape.line(p1, p2)
Vector p3 = p2.cpy().setAngle(oberserverAngle * 0.5f);
Vector p4 = p2.cpy().setAngle(-oberserverAngle * 0.5f);
shape.line(p1, p3);
shape.line(p1, p4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rotating a wrong vector. This should do it:

```
Vector2 angleVec = p2.cpy().sub(p1);

shape.line(p1, p2)
Vector p3 = p1.add(angleVec.cpy().setAngle(oberserverAngle * 0.5f));
Vector p4 = p1.add(angleVec.setAngle(-oberserverAngle * 0.5f));
shape.line(p1, p3);
shape.line(p1, p4);
```

To achieve the result as shown in your Image you'd have to Stretch the rotated angleVec's

Answer (score 1):

You should rather rotate the `oberserverAngle` vector since you want to get the field *on the left* from `oberserverAngle` and *on the right* from this. The `p2` seems to be meaningless here.

```
    Vector p3 = oberserverAngle.rotate(0.5f);
    Vector p4 = oberserverAngle.rotate(-0.5f);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p2.cpy().sub(p1).angle();
```

Method returns angle towards the positive y-axis and between 0 and 360.

i suggest you to use

```
float oberserverAngle = p2.angle(p1);
```

This method will return angle between to vector towards to positive y-axis between -180 and +180.

And if you want to find p3 and p4 angles dont multiply with 0.5f. 
Just add fov/2f angle to it.

```
float oberserverAngle = p2.angle(p1);
float fov=120f;

shape.line(p1, p2)
p2.sub(p1);//p2 became ray vector now you can set angle correctly.
Vector p3 = p2.cpy().setAngle(oberserverAngle + fov/2f).add(p1); // added p1 now for corrected position
Vector p4 = p2.cpy().setAngle(oberserverAngle - fov/2f).add(p1);
shape.line(p1, p3);
shape.line(p1, p4);
p2.add(p1);// turning back to p2 for later usages.
```